# How Can I use new Date().setHours(0,0,0) in a single line?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to create a new Date in JavaScript without the timestamp. I'm trying to use the setHours method. I noticed a strange behavior, if I create the object and in the same line I use the setHours, the result will be just numbers, but I don't want that, I want just the Date with the hours:minutes:seconds all setted to zero.

**
First Case, that's the desired result, but I want to do this in a single line**

```js
const today = new Date()
today.setHours(0,0,0)
console.log(today)
```

**Second Case, I'd like to do something like this, but with the output of the first case.**

```js
const today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0)
console.log(today)
```

Comment: `const today = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0))` [`setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) returns the date as a number.

Comment:  Which is of course somewhat crazy, so… just stick to two lines. Do you have a shortage of lines?

Comment: Indeed, always prefer readability and maintainability over cleverness and shorter code. We have things like webpack, parcel, babel, etc. to minify our code for us.

Comment: @deceze I need this to a special case, I am creating a super complex object, and one of the fields is calculated passing values to a function that returns the value to the field, that's the reason Why I want to do this in a single line, because I need to pass this value as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Ok, *worst case*, you create a helper function and simply do `midnightDate()` wherever you need this, so there’s really zero reason for this and never a special exceptional case…